# How to get the value of one element in a List in groovy/grails

Tags: list, grails, groovy, criteria, hibernate-criteria

After do a createCriteria query, I have a object list of only 1 item with 7 strings inside. That I want to do is get only one of this seven elements??

```
List<Object> result - com.test.MyService.getConfig(String, String, String, String, String, String, String)
```

This are the elements that I get in the list:

```
[name:John, surname:John city:Rome, car:BMW, country:Italy, day:Monday, color:Red,]
```

I want access for example only to get the string 'country' to can return it in a method:

I'm trying to do this:

```
result.get(4)
```

And I'm gettin this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
def oneObject = YourDomainClass.createCriteria().get{
     //add your criteria if any
}
return oneObject.country
```

You get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 1` because when you execute `YourDomainClass.createCriteria().list{}` you get a **list** of YourDomainClass objects (which has only one object). So if you want to use `YourDomainClass.createCriteria().list{}` you should execute:

```
def objects = YourDomainClass.createCriteria().list{}
if(objects) //check if any object is in list
    return objects[0].country
```

Comment: I can't access to .country

Comment: Please be more specific: what kind of error did you get with my solutions? Did you try both of them?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. Either just do `result.first().country`
2. Or if you are sure that criteria will return a single result always then use `get` instead of `list`.
3. And if you just need a single property then use projection to fetch that property only instead of whole object.

`def result = DomainClass.createCriteria().list { //or get
    resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
    projections {
        property("country", "country")
    }
}`

In this case when using `.list{}` to get value for country:

1. With result transformer `return result.first().country`
2. Without result transformer: `return result.first()`

When using `.get{}` instead of `.list{}`:

1. With result transformer `return result.country`
2. Without result transformer: `return result`